# Some meta state when create bridge on 22.04

Tags: 22.04, network-manager, network-bridge, nmcli

It is said that if the system use NetworkManager, you'd better use `nmcli`, or there may be conflictions between different management systems.

Suppose there is an ethernet connection named `eno1` whose ip address is `192.168.1.23/24` then I create bridge with these:

```
sudo nmcli con add ifname br0 type bridge con-name br0 stp no
sudo nmcli con add type bridge-slave ifname eno1 master br0

sudo nmcli con down br0
sudo nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.addresses '192.168.1.24/24'
sudo nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.gateway '192.168.1.1'
sudo nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.dns '192.168.1.1'
sudo nmcli connection modify br0 ipv4.method manual
sudo nmcli con up br0
```

After that, it seems to get into some meta status, that is, `ip r` shows that `eno1 with 192.168.1.23/24` is still used, and `br0 with 192.168.1.24/24` is `linkdown`.

The normal thing should be that the enslaved `eno1` is not used to route anymore and `br0` is up and used for routing.

When I put the machine to sleep then wake up, `br0` is finally used to route and the `eno1` route entry disappeared as supposed.

Why does the sleep cycle put it right and what is the equivalent commands to execute to put it right?